# What is the go equivalent of a typescript string union?

Tags: go, types

In typescript I can say

```
type S = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
```

and `S` will only accept the defined values.

How to achieve the same with golang `string` type?

Comment: You cannot, Go does not have literal types.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. But afaik go doesn't provide any out of the box support for enum.

```
type S string

const (
    One S = "one"
    Two S = "two"
    Three S = "three"
)
```